# Regular Expression to accept all the number with decimal from 0 to 168 followed by N or S

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to build a regular exp which will accept all the numbers from 0 to 168 followed by "N" or "S".

I have prepared the following regular exp which is working fine except that it considers 168.11 as valid input.

**Regular Exp:**

```
/\b([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[01][0-9]|16[0-8])(\.\d{1,2})?[N,S]?$/
```

**Valid:**

```
168S
11.2
 10
140
125N
130S
3S
3.2
168.00S
```

**Invalid:**

```
168.11
168.12S
168.12N
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: A very well formed question that shows your attempted regex and all valid and invalid examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex with optional matches:

```sh
^\s*(?:(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1[0-5]\d|16[0-7])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|168(?:\.0{1,2})?)[NS]?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vct9rd/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^\s*`: Match 0 or more horizontal spaces at start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group #1

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `\d`: A single digit to numbers from `0` to `9`
    - `|`: OR
    - `[1-9]\d`: Match numbers from `10` to `99`
    - `|`: OR
    - `1[0-5]\d`: Match numbers from `100` to `159`
    - `|`: OR
    - `16[0-7]`: Match numbers from `160` to `167`
  - `)`: End non-capture group #2
  - `(?:\.\d{1,2})?`: Match optional decimal point followed by 1 or 2 digits
  - `|`: OR
  - `168`: Match `168`
  - `(?:\.0{1,2})?`: Match optional `.0` or `.00`
- `)`: End non-capture group #1
- `[NS]?`: Match optional `N` or `S` before end
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
^ *(?!0|168\.0?[1-9]|169)(?:\d?\d|1[0-6]\d)(?:\.\d?\d)?[SN]?$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YsLLRF/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `*` - 0+ space characters.
- `(?!0|168\.0?[1-9]|169)` - Negative lookahead for a leading zero **or** literally "168." followed by decimal number containing anything other than zero **or** literally "169".
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\d?\d` - 1 Or 2 digits.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `1[0-6]\d` - A literal "1" followed by numbers 00 upto 69.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `(?:\.\d?\d)?` - A 2nd non-capture group (optional) for a decimal number (1-2 digits).
- `[SN]?` - Optionally match "S" or "N".
- `$` - End line anchor.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
^(?:(?:[0-9]|\d\d|1[0-5]\d|16[0-7])(?:\.\d\d+)?|168(?:\.0+))[NS]?$
```

with [regexr demo](https://regexr.com/5u48b)

[image]